# Big Commerce Variable %%GLOBAL_DeliveryDisclaimer%%

Tags: bigcommerce

In the Big Commerce file /snippets/ExpressCheckoutChooseShipper.html there is the global variable %%GLOBAL_DeliveryDisclaimer%%. Does anyone know where in admin this value is stored?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify it in `Snippets/CartShippingDeliveryDisclaimer.html` file.

You can do so e.g. in Design > More > Template Files > Snippets > `CartShippingDeliveryDisclaimer.html` > [cog icon] > Edit

Comment: Thank you. Seems like this is an unused %% variable as these usually refer to something in admin or something generated by php.